# select specific columns from first table with eager loading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have checked many solutions to get specific columns from first model with eager loading but nothing works in my case.

for example: I want specific columns from model `User` and want to get relationship data with eager loading without any join.

```
$users= User::select('name') // get one column from user table
->with(array('role_user' => function($query){
    $query->select('role_name'); // and select one column from pivot table
}))
->paginate(3);
```

when I don't use `User::select('name)`, it returns relationship data with eager load when I use select, it returns empty array.

How I can get specific columns from both tables using eager loading

Comment: You should always also select the primary and foreign keys when using eager loading

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly know, how you defined your relationship but Laravel has [some weird behavior](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/38074): You should always also select the primary and foreign keys:

```
$users= User::select(['id', 'name']) // get one column from user table
->with(array('role_user' => function($query){
    $query->select(['id', 'role_name']); // and select one column from pivot table
}))
->paginate(3);
```

You can simplify it to this:

```
$users= User::select(['id', 'name']) // get one column from user table
->with(['role_user:id,user_id,role_name']) // and select one column from pivot table
->paginate(3);
```

Comment: it is also returning empty array in relations but (id, name) columns from User model

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the schema of the two tables plus the relationship from the model? You probably need to add `user_id` to the `select()` inside `with()`

Comment: @shaedrich thanks! it worked.  foreign key  is required

Comment: If you're reading this in the future, checkout the weird behaviour. This answer addresses this issue well and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

We Never Know  the schemas and the relationships of your project.. But I assume You This Should Work

```
$users = User::select('id','name') 
               ->with(['role_user:id,user_id,role_name'])
               ->paginate(3);
```

In your User Model Relationships must be

```
public function role_user(){
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user'); // pivot table name
}
```

In your Role Model

```
 public function users(){
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user'); // pivot table name
}
```